# How Can I add security header Java soap request?

Tags: java, soap

I called a web-service like this and It works.

```
LimitRiskSorguServisOutputBean response;
LimitRiskSorguServisService service;
service = new LimitRiskSorguServisServiceLocator("https://rmuyetest.org/inb/rm-klkr-sorgu/hamveri");
LimitRiskSorguServis servicePort = service.getLimitRiskSorguServisPort(); 
LimitRiskSorguServisInputBean inputBean = new LimitRiskSorguServisInputBean();
inputBean.setName(""); //etc
response = servicePort.munferitLimitRiskSorgula(inputBean);
```

But now server added security header (authorization key).

How can I add this security header?